# How to set attribute (id) at collection fieldset (doctrine 2, zend framework 2)

Tags: javascript, collections, attributes, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

is it possible to set an id at a fieldset that's made by a collection? I've a couple of entities (user, addresses, attachments etc.), and in my user-entity i've several fieldsets that are made with a collection. So a user can have multiple addresses or attachments. My collections are build up like this:

```
$addressFieldset = new AddressFieldset($serviceManager);

$this->add(array(
   'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
   'name' => 'addresses',
   'options' => array(
       'label' => 'Choose address for user',
       'count' => 1,
       'should_create_template' => true,
       //'template_placeholder' => '__placeholder__',
       'allow_add' => true,
       'target_element' => $addressFieldset
       ),
   ));

$this->add(array(
     'name' => 'addAddress',
     'type' => 'button',
     'options' => array('label' => 'Add Address',
            ),
      ));
$this->get('addAddress')->setAttribute('onclick', 'return add_address()');
```

My problem is that I've multiple collections in my userfieldset. So when I want dynamically add some addresses (example that I use: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html), the example has the following javascript:

```
function add_address() {
    var currentCount = $('form > fieldset > fieldset').length;
    var template = $('form > fieldset > span').data('template');

    template = template.replace(/__index__/g, currentCount);

    $('form > fieldset').append(template);

    return false;
}
```

But, my problem is that if I use the example, it added addressfieldsets also under the attachments. What I want is something like:

```
function add_address() {
    var currentCount = $('form > #addressFieldset > fieldset').length;
    var template = $('form > #addressFieldset > span').data('template');

    template = template.replace(/__index__/g, currentCount);

    $('form > #addressFieldset').append(template);

    return false;
}
```

With this, I only access the addressFieldset, but how can I set an ID at the AddressFieldset?
My tree should look like:

```
<form>
    <fieldset id="addressFieldset">
        <legend>Choose addresses</legend>
        <fieldset>
            //Data
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="attachmentFieldset">
        <legend>Choose attachments</legend>
        <fieldset>
            //Data
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I don't know how to set the id's in the fieldsets. Please help

Answer (score 2):

One possible way of doing it is to extend `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormCollection` and register the extension as a replacement for the default `formCollection` helper.

*For purposes of this example, I'll assume your module is called `Application`.*

First, you need to define a custom class extending the aforementioned Zend helper. For my extensions/overrides I usually keep the same directory structure as Zend, except I replace *"Zend"* with the name of my module so, in my case, the class would reside in `module/Application/src/Application/Form/View/Helper/FormCollection.php`.

Once that's done, you can replace the helper by adding the following lines to your `module/Application/config/module.config.php` file:

```php
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'formCollection' => 'Application\Form\View\Helper\FormCollection',
    ),
),
```

This tells Zend that whenever a view helper called `formCollection` gets invoked, use this class instead of the default one.

Next, you need to override the [`render`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/7c65991e07194fbccb413f6a89c59c395193b519/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormCollection.php#L75) method. Unfortunately, you'll have to copy/paste contents of the original method into your class (as the generation of the `fieldset` tag is hardcoded) but it's a small price to pay if you want the functionality.

You will need to modify the bit that wraps the `$markup` variable in tags before returning the result.

Before we do that though, we need to define the attributes of the fieldset in the factory array. I decided put my fieldset attributes in a key called `fieldset_attributes` like this:

```php
$this->add(array(
    'type'    => 'Collection',
    'name'    => 'addresses',
    'options' => array(
        'label'                  => 'Choose address for user',
        'count'                  => 1,
        'allow_add'              => true,
        'allow_remove'           => true,
        'create_new_objects'     => true,
        'should_create_template' => true,
        'target_element'         => $addressFieldset,
        'attributes'             => array(
            'id' => 'addressFieldset',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Of course, you can name the key differently if you want or restructure the array, that's purely up to you. Just make sure you update the `render` method that we are about to modify accordingly.

So, the last thing to do is check for custom attributes when wrapping `$markup` and append them if any are found. For that we will modify lines [121](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/7c65991e07194fbccb413f6a89c59c395193b519/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormCollection.php#L121) to [125](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/7c65991e07194fbccb413f6a89c59c395193b519/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormCollection.php#L125) to look like this:

```php
$attributeString = '';
$options = $element->getOptions();
if (!empty($options['attributes'])) {
    $attributeString = ' ' . $this->createAttributesString($options['attributes']);
}

$markup = sprintf(
    '<fieldset%s><legend>%s</legend>%s</fieldset>',
    $attributeString,
    $label,
    $markup
);
```

If you refresh your page now, you'll see that `<fieldset>` has changed to `<fieldset id="addressFieldset">`!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just add it under the `attributes` for your element:

```
$this->add(array(
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'someId',
        'onclick' => 'return add_address()';
    ),
    // your other stuff, type, name, options, etc...
));
```

Comment: I've created the fieldset with id in my view. In zend there is noway to set a id at an formcollection, because that viewhelper only set the legend en the fieldset itself. So no attributes on the fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why ZF1's Form Decorators have been dropped in ZF2...

IMO the most effective way to decorate form elements is to "overrule" ZF2's Form View Helpers... even though I did it quite barbarically...

```
    <?php
    namespace Application\Helpers\View;

    use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
    use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormCollection as BaseFormCollection;

    class FormCollection extends BaseFormCollection
    {
        public function render(ElementInterface $element)
        {
            if($element->getAttribute('name') == 'usertype')
                return str_replace('<fieldset>', '<fieldset class="noborder">', parent::render($element));
            else
                return parent::render($element);
        }
    }
```